# Send SMS after onClick positiveButton is pressed

Tags: android, eclipse, text, sms

A dialog box opens after a "panic" button is pressed. the dialog box is confirming that the presser is indeed panicking.

After the "YES" button is pressed, I want to send an SMS to a number (just using mine atm)

This is what I have so far:

In the main menu:

```
public Panic panic;

public void panicSOS(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("SOS Beacon");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");

    builder.setPositiveButton("ON", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {            

                                        //Sets to panic mode
                                        panic.sendRequest(null);
                                        dialog.dismiss(); } } );

    builder.setNegativeButton("OFF", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                        //Sets to chill mode

                                        dialog.dismiss(); } } );

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Then in the panic class

```
public class Panic extends Activity {

String phoneNumber = "04********"; // TODO: should not be static
String message = "Check-in Request";

/**
 * Factory method for creating a launch intent.
 * @param context
 * @param payload extra string input
 * @return
 */
public static Intent makeIntent(Context context, String payload) {
    return new Intent(context, Panic.class);
}

// sends a checkin request the client instantly via SMS
public void sendRequest(View view) {        
    SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    manager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);        
}
```

Getting a null pointer exception and a few other errors. Any tips?

Commencing gross swath of logcat grossness

09-23 02:22:22.675: D/AndroidRuntime(4518): Shutting down VM
09-23 02:22:22.675: W/dalvikvm(4518): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41800d88)

09-23 02:22:22.675: E/AndroidRuntime(4518): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

09-23 02:22:22.675: E/AndroidRuntime(4518): Process: com.illusivemen.smartwatchclient, PID: 4518

09-23 02:22:22.675: E/AndroidRuntime(4518): java.lang.NullPointerException

09-23 02:22:22.675: E/AndroidRuntime(4518):     at com.illusivemen.smartwatchclient.MainMenu$2.onClick(MainMenu.java:96)

09-23 02:22:22.675: E/AndroidRuntime(4518):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:171)

09-23 02:22:22.675: E/AndroidRuntime(4518):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

09-23 02:22:22.675: E/AndroidRuntime(4518):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)

09-23 02:22:22.675: E/AndroidRuntime(4518):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)

09-23 02:22:22.675: E/AndroidRuntime(4518):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

09-23 02:22:22.675: E/AndroidRuntime(4518):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

09-23 02:22:22.675: E/AndroidRuntime(4518):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)

09-23 02:22:22.675: E/AndroidRuntime(4518):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)

09-23 02:22:22.675: E/AndroidRuntime(4518):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

09-23 02:22:24.455: I/Process(4518): Sending signal. PID: 4518 SIG: 9

09-23 02:39:04.480: D/AndroidRuntime(5298): Shutting down VM

09-23 02:39:04.480: W/dalvikvm(5298): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception 
(group=0x41800d88)

09-23 02:39:04.490: E/AndroidRuntime(5298): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

09-23 02:39:04.490: E/AndroidRuntime(5298): Process: com.illusivemen.smartwatchclient, PID: 5298

09-23 02:39:04.490: E/AndroidRuntime(5298): java.lang.NullPointerException

09-23 02:39:04.490: E/AndroidRuntime(5298):     at com.illusivemen.smartwatchclient.MainMenu$2.onClick(MainMenu.java:96)

09-23 02:39:04.490: E/AndroidRuntime(5298):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:171)

09-23 02:39:04.490: E/AndroidRuntime(5298):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

09-23 02:39:04.490: E/AndroidRuntime(5298):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)

09-23 02:39:04.490: E/AndroidRuntime(5298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)

09-23 02:39:04.490: E/AndroidRuntime(5298):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

09-23 02:39:04.490: E/AndroidRuntime(5298):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

09-23 02:39:04.490: E/AndroidRuntime(5298):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)

09-23 02:39:04.490: E/AndroidRuntime(5298):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)

09-23 02:39:04.490: E/AndroidRuntime(5298):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

09-23 02:39:05.980: I/Process(5298): Sending signal. PID: 5298 SIG: 9

Comment: post your logcat so we can determine those 'few other errors'

Comment: I guess your "panic" is null on your onclicklistener. Can we see where you define it?

Comment: Try to call dismiss(); alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Panic` normal java class then no need to extend Activity in it. if `Panic` is Activity then instead of calling method by creating object of `Panic` use an utility class and use in both Activity's as:

```
public class UtilityClass {

String phoneNumber = "04********"; // TODO: should not be static
String message = "Check-in Request";

public static Intent makeIntent(Context context, String payload) {
    return new Intent(context, Panic.class);
}

// sends a checkin request the client instantly via SMS
public void sendRequest() {        
    SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    manager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);        
}
```

Now call `sendRequest` from AlertDialog and Activity as:

```
new UtilityClass().sendRequest();
```

Comment: I don't know who you are, or where you're from, but I'm wishing you the best right now.